# how to find distance between two markers in openlayers?

Tags: dictionary, openlayers

Hi i want to know how to find the distance between two markers in openlayers.

```
var distance = distanceBetweenMarkers(latLon1, latLon2){
//code to find the distance between latLon1, latLon2

}
```

pleae help me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create points from your `LonLat` and call `distanceTo` method from `Geometry.Point` [1].

```
p1 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(latLon1.lon,latLon1.lat);
p2 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(latLon2.lon,latLon2.lat);
len = p1.distanceTo(p2);
```

1 - http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Point-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.Point.distanceTo